# Password requirements for Azure SQL marketplace deployment

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

After deploying the ARM Template/Parameters/createUiDefinition files to the marketplace, the blade configuration works but the summary indicates 'Validation Failed' with code InvalidTemplate throwing at the Azure SQL password field. Adding Regex constraints to the password also has not fixed this error. Deployment works perfect from powershell/Template resources in the Portal.

What is the correct definition of an Azure SQL password for deploying to the marketplace?

Edit:
Defining password in **createUiDefinition.json**  as:

```
{
"name": "administratorLoginPassword",
"type": "Microsoft.Compute.CredentialsCombo",
"label": {
    "password": "Password",
    "confirmPassword": "Confirm password"
    },
"toolTip": {
    "password": ""
    },
"constraints": {
    "required": true,
    "customPasswordRegex": "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\\d])(?=.*[@#$%^&£*\\-_+=[\\]{}|\\\\:',?\\/`~\"\"();!])[a-zA-z\\d@#$%^&£*\\-_+=[\\]{}|\\\\:',?\\/`~\"\"();!]{8,}$",
"customValidationMessage": "The password must contain at least 12 characters, with at least 1 letter and 1 number."
    },
"options": {
    "hideConfirmation": false
    },
"osPlatform": "Windows",
"visible": true
}
```

Defining password in **MainTemplate.json**  as:

```
"administratorLoginPassword": {
  "type": "securestring",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The administrator login password for the Essentials Database."
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you define the password?

Comment: Did you use"pwd": {
            "type": "securestring"
        }?